# Is this a viable method for graphene production?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, carbon-allotropes

In a cup of warm water add sugar until it no longer dissolves then add a few spoonfuls more of sugar.

Drop in a small amount of graphite powder into the sugar water mixture. Stir it up well. There should be a thin black film on top of the liquid.

Let it set for a few days.

The sugar crystals will grow on the graphene surface similar to how rock candy grows.

The sugar crystals grow on the bottom of the floating film of graphite and once heavy enough the graphene and sugar crystal wafer will sink. And then the process repeats.

Is this possible with graphite powder in water as a film or is a thin solid piece of graphite necessary for sugar crystal growth?

Comment: It is likely that what you get are graphite-coated sugar crystals. Why do you think this might produce graphene?

Comment: I know that if you add Graphite powder to water a thin film of Graphite appears on surface of water. It likes to group itself centrally in the liquid and on top. Is it necessary to chill the sugar water solution to prevent (or attempt to prevent) shearing ? Maybe instead of simply dumping the Graphite powder into the saturated sugar water you first mix up a lot of Graphite powder with a liquid (not necessarily water) and use an eye dropper to add the Graphite mix to the sugar water?

Comment: But where do you go beyond a thin film of graphite flakes? Graphene is not the same as graphite flakes.

Comment: When making rock candy the sugar in the saturated sugar water wants to latch onto things submerged in the solution and forms crystals on the object. Since the Graphite sits as a film on top of the liquid the crystals will grow on the nearest surface which is the bottom of the Graphite film. Will the accumulated crystals on the Graphite film cleave the underside and by its weight sink?

Comment: Also Hydrogen Peroxide 3% (do not use stronger concentrations!) could be later used (or warm water) to dissolve the sugar from the Graphene and Sugar wafer that was produced.

Comment: OK I get the idea. But most likely the answer is no since the weight of a sugar crystal is enough to sink a graphite flake and there is nothing strong enough in the surface tension holding it on the surface that would cause the flakes to cleave. This is hard to prove, but easy to test if you have a test for graphene, that is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wonder if use of different mediums to suspend the Graphite mixture in before adding to sugar water or if different temperatures of the sugar water may be helpful. So what if you froze the top of the sugar water and Graphite film would that provide a viable anchor point from which cleaving may be achieved by sugar crystal growth?

Comment: Excellent and many thanks. I am sure of it that if the surface is frozen or semi frozen then it would provide a point from which graphene will cleave off. If this is indeed true then they will have to call this the White and Black method or the Black and White method lol :P